# How can I programmatically determine if path is protected?

Tags: windows, winapi, uac, admin-rights

Is there any way to determine if a windows path is protected (i.e. if copying a file to it requires admins rights)? I was unable to a winapi function for this or an official list of windows protected paths.

So far, I know that C:, C:\Program Files and C:\Windows are protected and C:/Users/ is not, but I don't want to rely on trial by error.

Comment: I refer you to David Heffernan's [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19995387/218597) to a similar question. As he mentions, Windows security is a complex beast (this is a _good thing_), so it is not simply a case of knowing if a path is "protected".

Comment: Yes. Try to write to the location, and handle the exception if it fails.